# Unauthorized to use Microsoft Graph Calendars API using curl/postman

Tags: curl, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to interact with Calendars using Microsoft Graph. First, I have registered the app in Azure, generated a secret and set app permissions: `User.Read.All` and `Calendars.ReadWrite` and then granted admin access.

Then, I run the following commands:

1. Obtain access token:

   ```
   curl -X POST \
     https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
     -d 'client_id=<client_id>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=<client_secret>&grant_type=client_credentials'
   ```
2. After getting the access token, I get the list of users (it will be just one user - myself)

   ```
   curl -X GET \
     https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>'
   ```
3. I get the list of users, get my user id, and try to get the list of my calendars:

   ```
   curl -X GET \
     https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_id>/calendars \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>'
   ```

   I get the following 401 error:

   ```
   {
       "error": {
           "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
           "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '<tenant_id>' does not exist.",
           "innerError": {
               "request-id": "<request_id>",
               "date": "2019-04-06T18:22:32"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

One more thing - when I go to [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and login with the same account and make the above calls, it does return the users and I see myself (but with a different id).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to access this mailbox from Outlook on the Web?

Comment: Did you have more than one tenant with your account? If yes, it can be explained. When you login using Graph Explorer, it will use the default tenant. But you obtained the access token with a different tenant. The userid of the same user account in different tenant will be different.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur - yes, I can login to outlook.live.com with my live username (same as the one I use to login to Azure)

Comment: @TonyJu - I use the default tenant's ID when obtaining the access token; it's the same tenant ID that shows in the error - this is what confuses me.

Comment: @Andrey I see. You can try to use common instead of tenant id. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Could you add the token you're getting to the question? That might help clear up what is going on here.

Comment: What helped me greatly in this case is taking the token and inspecting it on https://jwt.ms This should show you the things you need.

Comment: @TonyJu I tried that, didn't make any difference unfortunately

Comment: @Stephan I just did, and i see the expected roles ("roles": [
    "User.Read.All",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite"
  ],).
 What else should I check there?

Comment: @andrey you're using the `v2.0` endpoint. I didn't spot that upfront. You should try it with the v1 endpoint. Do you have the unencoded token for us? Without the signature.

Comment: @Stephan I am not sure which parts of the unencoded token are safe to post here - what exactly would you need to see from there?

Comment: @Stephan - I tried using v1 endpoint for getting the token, but then the request to get the users fails with "Invalid token". Any ideas?